# Set GWT Line Chart mirrorLog

Tags: java, gwt, linechart

I have a GWT Line Chart that includes negative numbers along the horizontal axis. I'd like to use a log scale to present this data, but I'm not sure how to set the 'mirrorLog' property of the HAxis.

I can do `hAxis.setLogScale(true);` but this doesn't handle negative values. I'm looking for something like `hAxis.setScaleType("mirrorLog")`, but it appears that doesn't exist. I'm using gwt-charts-0.9.10.jar as well.

Thanks in advancce.

```
    // Prepare the data
    DataTable dataTable = DataTable.create();
    dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Data Name");
    dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Line Name";

    dataTable.addRows(myArray.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++) {
        dataTable.setValue(i, 0, String.valueOf(myArray.get(i)));
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<values.size(); i++){
        dataTable.setValue(i, 1, String.valueOf(values.get(i)));
    }

    // Set options
    LineChartOptions options = LineChartOptions.create();
    HAxis hAxis = HAxis.create("HAxis Name");
    options.setBackgroundColor("#f0f0f0");
    options.setFontName("Tahoma");
    options.setHAxis(hAxis);
    options.setVAxis(VAxis.create("VAxis Name"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So before I asked this question yesterday, I tried making a CustomHAxis class that was an exact copy of the HAxis class included in the jar with the addition of a setScaleType() function. This did not work because the setHAxis() function of LineChartOptions only accepts an HAxis.

The solution is to make a custom HAxis class that extends HAxis and then add a setScaleType() function to that.

```
public class CustomHAxis extends HAxis {
/**
 * Default constructor.
 * 
 * @return a new object instance
 */
public static CustomHAxis create() {
    return createObject().cast();
}

/**
 * Constructor with title.
 * 
 * @param title
 *            axis title
 * 
 * @return a new object instance
 */
public static CustomHAxis create(String title) {
    CustomHAxis hAxis = createObject().cast();
    hAxis.setTitle(title);
    return hAxis;
}

protected CustomHAxis() {
}

public final native void setScaleType(String scaleType) /*-{
    this.scaleType = scaleType;
}-*/;
}
```